# Javascript/jQuery compress an image correct oreantation post and save to a controller using Ajax Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 framework. My application requirements are to do a client side image compression to minimize data bandwidth consumption. To achieve this I am looking around for solutions in JavaScript and/ or jQuery. From my previous implementation of image upload as multi-part data using form post I discovered that some images flip upon upload to the server so I need to do a client side orientation correction before image upload. The images are to be uploaded using ajax. The resulting images must have 240x 240 dimensions.

Comment: Need to do your own research into all of this. Come back when you have specific code related problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively good question I don't know why some people are down voting it. Maybe its wrong punctuation in the question.

The best way to compress the image is to draw it in an html canvas first. Assuming you are using file input

```
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("dstv_full_image").files[0]);

oFReader.onloadend = function() {
         //declare the exif variable
         var exif =EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(this.result));
         //dynamicaly create the canvas 
         var canvas= document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
        canvas.width  = 160;
        canvas.height = 160;
        canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
        //declare canvas context
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var img = new Image();
        //then on image load else code will run before and the result will be a black uploaded image!
        img.onload = function() {
              var orientation =exif.Orientation;;

switch (orientation) {
  case "2":
    // horizontal flip
    ctx.translate(width, 0)
    ctx.scale(-1, 1)
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,240, 240);
    break
  case "3":
    // 180° rotate left
    //ctx.translate(width, height)
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI)
    ctx.drawImage(img, -240, -240,240, 240);
    break
  case "4":
    // vertical flip
    //ctx.translate(0, height)
    ctx.scale(1, -1)
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,240, 240);
    break
  case "5":
    // vertical flip + 90 rotate right
    ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI)
    ctx.scale(1, -1)
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, -240,240, 240);
    break
  case "6":
    // 90° rotate right
    ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI)
    //ctx.translate(0, -height)
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, -240,240, 240);
    break
  case "7":
    // horizontal flip + 90 rotate right
    ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI)
    //ctx.translate(width, -height)
    ctx.scale(-1, 1)
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, -240,240, 240);
    break
  case "8":
    // 90° rotate left
    //alert("steve")
    ctx.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI)
    //ctx.translate(-width, 0)
    ctx.drawImage(img, -240,0, 240, 240);
    break

   default:
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0 ,0, 240, 240);
   break 
}
var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL();

                    var request = $.ajax({
                                url: "settings_picture_save",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {quest_id : dataURL},
                                dataType: "html"
                                });

                           request.done(function(msg) {
                           console.log(msg);


                              }


                           })
                       }
           img.src =this.result;
}
```

of course don't forget to include the exif JavaScript library and the following function

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer (base64) {
    base64 = base64.replace(/^data\:([^\;]+)\;base64,/gmi, '');
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Then on your controller

```
public function settings_picture_save(Request $request){
   $src = Input::get('quest_id');
       //get the base-64 from data
   //$base64_str = substr($myquest_id, strpos($myquest_id, ",")+1);
   $src = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $src);
   $src = str_replace(' ', '+', $src);

   //decode base64 string
   $image = base64_decode($src);
   $png_url = "product-".time().".png";
   $path = ('uploads/' . $png_url);

   //Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);
   // write image
   $result = file_put_contents($path, $image); 
   echo json_encode('done');
}
```

of course don't forget the necessary routes

Comment: Thank you . I had no idea how to correctly implement the exif.js library also my saved images were back that's why  I tried as much as possible to post an open ended question. I nearly gave up on this approach.